# Is 'need' a verb or noun in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

In an address to the UN, Greta Thunberg said: "Everything needs to change -- and it has to start today."

I was wondering, is 'need' a verb in this sentence? Or is 'change' the verb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To change" is an infinitive, used as a noun as the direct object of the transitive verb "needs".

What's to wonder?

Comment: So it is a verb in this sentence? English is my third language.

Comment: @Steven, correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with need is it acts as a main verb sometimes, helping  verb sometimes  and  as  a noun sometimes.

> **Everything needs to change**
>
> **You need not stay here**
>
> **I am in need of  your help**

In sentence  1 need is a main verb , in  2  it is  a helping verb  and in 3  it is a noun